# Can't switch Upstream Proxy when Http Error occur

Tags: python, mitmproxy

#### Problem Description

When I try to use `flow.live.change_upstream_proxy_server(address)` to switch the upstream Proxy in `Error()` method from [HttpEvents](https://docs.mitmproxy.org/master/addons-events/#http-events), the upstream proxy stay the same and does not change.
I based my code on [this](https://github.com/mitmproxy/mitmproxy/blob/master/examples/contrib/change_upstream_proxy.py) example.

#### Steps to reproduce the behavior:

1. launch Mitm with an upstream and script:
   `mitmdump --mode upstream:182.52.74.76:34084 --ssl-insecure -s scripts/watcher.py`
2. wait for upstream proxy to fail
3. let watcher.py renew the upstream proxy

#### Current result:

(can't post image directly due to lack of reputation)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/YUpRB.png

At this point we assume that the upstream proxy is now changed to `103.199.84.54:8080`, but when we renew a request, we can see in the error message that the proxy is still the same (`182.52.74.76:34084`) instead of `103.199.84.54:8080` :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ko95D.png

#### Watcher.py

```py
from mitmproxy import http
from mitmproxy import ctx

import requests
import json
import typing

#***** Some fetching to get new proxy from my API*****

def getNewProxy() -> typing.Tuple[str, int]:
    id = str(getRandID())
    params = { 'id': 'eq.' + id, 'select': 'proxy'}
    response = str(requests.get(url = url, params = params).json()[0]['proxy'])[7:].split(':')
    proxIP = (response[0], int(response[1]))
    return (proxIP)

class Events:
    
    def error(self, flow: http.HTTPFlow):
        ctx.log.info(str(flow.server_conn.address))
        pAddr = getNewProxy()
        ctx.log.info("Switching upstream proxy to: " + pAddr[0] + ":" + str(pAddr[1]))
        flow.live.change_upstream_proxy_server(pAddr)

addons = [
    Events()
]
```

#### System Information

mitmproxy --version:

```sh
$ mitmdump --version
Mitmproxy: 5.2
Python:    3.7.3
OpenSSL:   OpenSSL 1.1.1g  21 Apr 2020
Platform:  Linux-4.19.0-9-amd64-x86_64-with-debian-10.4
```

Thanks for your help, really annoyed by this problem right now !

Comment: Please do not post console output as image. Console output is text and should be treated though. Second: Please do not report issues here you have already posted on the mitmproxy issues project - SO is not a bug tracker.

Comment: Thanks for the tips.
But how was I suppose to know it was a bug at that time ? Thought SO was a place to ask for help when you are facing a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that Mitproxy itself does not support retrying requests at the moment.
See [this](https://github.com/mitmproxy/mitmproxy/issues/3628).